# Creating a db config file in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, config

I am trying to create a windows form application in vb.net that should work with user specific database meaning the user creates the database and gives it his/her own name after which the system imports my database file and creates the tables from it then creates a config file that it uses for connection.

I have so far created a form which the the user will fill in with the database settings save and they will be stored in the application settings variables like this

```
    Private Sub Save()
    My.Settings.MServer = TxtServer.Text
    My.Settings.MDbUser = TxtDbUname.Text
    My.Settings.MDbPass = TxtDbPwd.Text
    My.Settings.MDb = TxtDb.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
    MessageBox.Show("Dtabase settings saved correctly", "Database settings")
    My.Settings.Reload()
    Application.Restart()
End Sub
```

The problem is that having put this under the settings section of the menu on the main form, it poses a vulnerability to the system as it can be changed by anyone who gains access to the computer in which it is installed.

I would therefore like to ask

1. Is there a way that I can have it as part of the installer?
2. If yes then how can I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: Of course it's possible, but there are as many ways to do this as there are programmers in the world. We need you to make an attempt first and come back here with questions as you have specific problems with your implementation.

Comment: I am just asking for a clue because I have never done this. I am used to creating the connection details problematically and ensuring they remain the same on production since they are compiled with the application but this of dynamic connection is new. would appreciate your help

Comment: ADO.net, Nuget package from Oracle for MySQL and app.config accessed from code by My.Settings to store connection string.

Comment: Any links to a tutorial or such will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
Create a system settings variable that has the user set it's value then create a form from which the user will enter the database values 
after that on the code loading your main form or even the login form do create an if statement to check if the user settings are set else load the form, for the user to enter and save them like this:

The application settings definition
[image: Setings]

Then add this code before loading your login/ main form

```
  if  My.Settings.MServer = String.Empty AndAlso
      My.Settings.MDbUser = String.Empty AndAlso
      My.Settings.MDbPass = String.Empty AndAlso
      My.Settings.MDb = String.Empty Then
 MySettingsForm.Show()
 Else
'Load the next part either the login or main form'
End If
```

On the Mydbsettings form add this code under the save Button's onclick event to save the settings

```
    My.Settings.MServer = TxtServer.Text
    My.Settings.MDbUser = TxtDbUname.Text
    My.Settings.MDbPass = TxtDbPwd.Text
    My.Settings.MDb = TxtDb.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
    MessageBox.Show("Database settings saved correctly", "Database settings")
    My.Settings.Reload()
    Application.Restart()
```

Comment: Thanks It helped alot